# CSV correct line endings

Tags: csv, line-endings

I have csv rows like this:

```
'UTAS114_1','Aqua Sphere''\n'
```

But the line endings aren't understood by excel and everything goes into the first row. How do I fix them?

Answer (score 6):

It might be of interest that there's a [RFC for CSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) and that explicitly uses CRLF as line separator as well:

> Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line break (CRLF). For example:

```
   aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
   zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that the CSV was not generated on a Windows machine. Excel, I assume, expects `\r\n` at the end of every line.

Answer (score 1):

This is because newlines on Windows are different from those on Unix based systems.

Open the file in a text editor and do a find for `\n` and replace with `\r\n`, then save. Now when you open it lines should break correctly.